# How to do case insensitive search using querybuilder rest api in cq

Tags: rest, aem, query-builder

How to use case insensitive search in Querybuilder REST API in CQ5.  This is my query [localhost path query](http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=/content/tempfolder&type=nt:unstructured&property=jcr:content&property.value=test) .
Here i want to add fn:lower-case to my property. But it is not working.

```
                  property=fn:lower-case(@jcr:content)
```

This code is not working in querybuilder REST API. The same logic i can able to do using Xpath
like `[(fn:lower-case(@jcr:content), 'test']` and it's working fine, when i used in Querybuilder Java API. The same logic need to implement querybuilder REST API as well.

Where i need to add `fn:lower-case` into query `&property=jcr:content&property.value=test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will need to write your own code to do this, unfortunately.  I saw several postings that talk through how to do this, including the following:

- http://www.wemblog.com/2013/04/how-to-create-custom-query-predicate-in.html
- http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2013-07-10/custom-predicateevaluators-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-love/

Comment: I have custom predicates for java. But i am using Java Querybuilder. I am using querybuilder REST API. That means i am calling through url like this  "http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=/content/tempfolder&type=nt:unstructured&property=jcr:content&property.value=test"

Comment: Right, but once you implement the predicate then you can use it in your REST API query.  That first URL I posted shows how you can enter a predicate at HOST:PORT/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html.  That page has the link to generate results in JSON--your querybuilder.json link.  So the key is to add the predicate on the server-side in Java code so when you add custom querystring parameters to your URL the server will recognize them and know how to handle them.  I don't think there is any way to customize only in the URL without also developing your server-side code to handle it.