# AEM 6.3 Query builder - How to search for case insensitive?

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-63

How can we make the query to ignore case sensitivity of the `property.value` ?

Our query:

```
path=/content/central-content/jcr:content/main/decline_letter
property.value=0091A
property=@letterNumber
type=nt:unstructured
```

Works for `0091A` but fails for `0091a`

Comment: have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367480/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-using-querybuilder-rest-api-in-cq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fulltext` seemed to be helping/working.

```
path=/content/central-content/jcr:content/main/decline_letter
fulltext=0091A
property=@letterNumber
type=nt:unstructured
orderby.case=ignore
```

`fulltext` may not be a good solution is we have to be searching among a lot of nodes/data. In our case, we search for a very minimal number of nodes.